# How to manage 429 errors in axios with react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, axios

I have a react native app that uses MongoDB as the database with express and node js I also use Axios to communicate with the client to the server

Now the app constantly sends and receives data from the database rapidly, e.g a user makes as much as 3 to 4 requests to and from the backend per second when the app is in use,

Everything works fine but there are a lot of 429 errors, how to handle this error or prevent it from occurring without compromising the users experiences a lot?

this below is the axios instanace

```
const instance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://9rv324283.ngrok.io' })
```

this below is fetching the data from the database

```
<NavigationEvents
onWillFocus={() => {

  try {

    const response = await instance.get('fetchNewDishes');

    this.setState({data: response.data})

  } catch(err) {

    console.log(err)

  }

}}>
```

this below is send data to the database

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  instance.patch(`/postNewDish/${this.state.dish}`)}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#555', padding: 15 }}>Post Dish</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: How many request do you send in a minute ? 429 is throttling error.

Comment: around 10 to 15 @BoraSumer

Comment: I think I see it, you forgot to add async to your function for your await to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use axios interceptors to actually trace the error handling in axios , see below example :

```
import ax from 'axios';
import {config} from '../global/constant';

const baseUrl = config.apiUrl;

let axios = ax.create({
  baseURL: baseUrl,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
});

axios.interceptors.request.use(req => handleRequest(req));
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => handleResponse(res),
  rej => handleError(rej),// here if its an error , then call handleError and do what you want to do with error.
);

// sending the error as promise.reject
const handleError = error => {
  let errorResponse = {...error};
  console.log({...error}, 'error');
  return Promise.reject({
    data: errorResponse.response.data,
    code: errorResponse.response.status,
  });
};
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Ok it is good to use axios interceptors, but how will this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in control of the backend? It is possible there is a middleware that limits requests such as `express-rate-limit`

Make sure to either disable these middlewares, or allow many more requests per minute in the middleware configs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play around with this using https://httpstat.us/429/cors, which always returns error 429 with [retry-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) set to 5 (seconds), and came up with this using [axios-retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry):

```
import axios from "axios";
import axiosRetry from "axios-retry";

let instance = axios.create({ baseURL: "https://httpstat.us" });

axiosRetry(instance, {
  retryCondition: (e) => {
    return (
      axiosRetry.isNetworkOrIdempotentRequestError(e) ||
      e.response.status === 429
    );
  },
  retryDelay: (retryCount, error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      const retry_after = error.response.headers["retry-after"];
      if (retry_after) {
        return retry_after;
      }
    }

    // Can also just return 0 here for no delay if one isn't specified
    return axiosRetry.exponentialDelay(retryCount);
  }
});

// Test for error 429
instance({
  url: "/429/cors",
  method: "get"
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("429 res: ", res);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("429 e: ", e);
  });

// Test to show that code isn't triggered by working API call
instance({
  url: "/200/cors",
  method: "get"
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("200 res: ", res);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("200 e: ", e);
  });
```

I'm working on adding this to axios-retry properly for https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry/issues/72